Django and SQL Server GIS error create point
i'm using django and sql server database when i try to create point to my model it keep giving me this error

ProgrammingError at /api/common/v1/location/ ('42000', "[42000]
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]No column name
was specified for column 1 of 'subquery'. (8155) (SQLExecDirectW)")
this is my model

class Location(TimeStampedWithNamesModel):
    """this class for general Location model."""

    district = models.ForeignKey(
        District,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="district_locations",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    city_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    region_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    country_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    polygon = models.PolygonField(null=True, blank=True)
    point = models.PointField(null=True, blank=True)
    area = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_polygon = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    diameter = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        """this Meta class for the location model."""

        ordering = ("-created_at",)
        unique_together = UNIQUE_TOGETHER_NAME_WITH_COMPANY
        verbose_name = _("Location")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Location")

and for my setting
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": config(
            "SQL_ENGINE", default="mssql"
        ),
        "NAME": config(
            "SQL_DATABASE", default="xxx"
        ),
        "USER": config("SQL_USER", default="admin"),
        "PASSWORD": config("SQL_PASSWORD", default="xxxx"),
        "HOST": config("SQL_HOST", default="xxxxx"),
        "PORT": config("SQL_PORT", default="1433"),
        "ATOMIC_REQUESTS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
        }
    },
}

note that another models are work fine I can create and list and update them

where is command code?
